# java changing value of hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

i have quick question,  what I am trying to do here is to, get the Student from HashMap and adds a double mark to Student's mark.

lets say i have class called Student and Student class has method called addToMark() and Hashmap called `theStudent = new HashMap<String, Student>`.

```
public void addExtraMark(String studentNumber, double mark) {
    if(stuentNumber != null && mark >= 0) {
        Student extraMark = theStudent.get(studentNumber);
        extraMark.addToMark(mark)};
    }
}
```

my question is, does mark adds to hashmap? automatically? or do i have to use

```
theStudent.put(studentNumber, extraMark);
```

on the bottome of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Student extraMark` is a reference to that Student, anything you do to the reference will be reflected in the HashMap.

No, you do not have to make the call:

```
theStudent.put(studentNumber, extraMark);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
Student extraMark = theStudent.get(studentNumber);
extraMark.addToMark(mark)}};
```

If the `studentNumber` doesn't exist in the hash map, `get` returns `null`.  Then `extraMark.addToMark` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

So you have to check yourself, e.g.:

```
Student extraMark;
if (theStudent.containsKey(studentNumber)) {
    extraMark = theStudent.get(studentNumber);
} else {
    extraMark = new Student(.......);
    theStudent.put(studentNumber, extraMark);
}
extraMark.addToMark(mark);
```

or you do the `get` first and check the result for `null`.

**Note:** I've assumed that your question "does mark adds to hashmap" meant "would it add a new student to the hashmap if it weren't already there", but after rereading your question, I'm not clear on what you meant.